# SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused. Getting this error 3-4 times/week

Tags: mysql, laravel, connection

Facing issue on server where query is being used on daily basis to sync, process and serve the data. But 3-4times/week this error gets encountered by sentry.

Answer (score 0):

Were this error to happen consistently it would indicate a firewall issue or the wrong port. However, since it works and randomly gives you this error a few times a week, it would seem that the most likely cause is the MySQL server is crashing/restarting. Check the MySQL logs around the time you get the error and you should be able to determine the cause.